# Tabs does not work with mootools on joomla

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, joomla, tabs, mootools

Front-end article editing on Joomla! uses Mootools and my template uses Bootstrap (custom joomla) and jquery (1.12.4).

Edit article is divided into tabs, which do not work. When I load form via <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd> everything works ok, but on normal load I can find an error in console:

```
VM14108:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :
at Object.f.exec (mootools-core.js?5347180…:28)
at Object.success (mootools-core.js?5347180…:168)
at Object.e.extend.$owner (mootools-core.js?5347180…:38)
at Object.onStateChange (mootools-core.js?5347180…:159)
at Object.e.extend.$owner (mootools-core.js?5347180…:38)
```

Linked line contains only some joomla options in Ajax. Part of it:

```
{"system.paths":{"root":"","base":""},"system.keepalive":{"interval":840000,"uri":"\/component\/ajax\/?format=json"}
```

I tried removed mootools but result was, that I see only one tab in tab menu.

Now when I click on tab in tabs menu nothing happen.